# Strange issue with slideDown in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I've got this script https://jsfiddle.net/n4yua7h0/1/
It's working perfectly fine on JSFiddle, as you can see.
Yet, for some reason, when used in production it's starting to behave oddly.
The `slideDown` function does not fire at the very first try, but later it fires just fine. 
There's virtually no difference between HTML and JS structure in JSFiddle and production code. Everything is identical.
Production site is working on JBOSS 7 server with JSF, and those particular `level-2` divs are generated in java. But when parsed to HTML it's same code as in the Fiddle.
What's the source of that issue and how to fix it? Might it be tha JSF/Java origin?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
function dropMouse(){
  $('.level-2').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    if(self.find('.content').children().length <= 3){
     self.find('.roll-button').addClass('hide');
      self.find('.content').addClass('blocky');
    } else{
      self.find('.category-with-checkbox:gt(2)').addClass('hide');
      self.mouseenter(function(){   
        self.find('roll-button').addClass('active');
        self.find('.category-with-checkbox:gt(2)').slideDown('slow').removeClass('hide');
      })
      self.mouseleave(function(){
        self.find('roll-button').removeClass('active');
        self.find('.category-with-checkbox:gt(2)').slideUp('slow').addClass('hide');
      })
    }
  })
}
dropMouse();

});
```

```css
.level-2 {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.category-with-checkbox {
  width: 100%
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.roll-button {
  width: 100%
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
.blocky {
  height: 75px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="level-2">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
  </div>
  <div class="roll-button">^</div>
</div>
<div class="level-2">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
  </div>
  <div class="roll-button">^</div>
</div>
<div class="level-2">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
    <div class="category-with-checkbox">s</div>
  </div>
  <div class="roll-button">^</div>
</div>
```

You may:

1. Need to import `jQuery` in your HTML.
2. Need to wrap your javascript in `$(document).ready(function() {...});`.

JSFiddle does both of those things for you with the Javascript settings button

Comment: Done and done. Still, it does not work as it should. I'm going slightly mad because of that. It's not due to old jQuery in the project. It's not the code difference. I've tried everything I could come up with to no avail. I'm suspecting Java/JSF to be at fault here, but I don't see why they would, to be honest.

Comment: Perhaps a CSS rule is modifying the layout? Or a javascript is messing up jQuery. Try a simple `$('.blah').click(function() {$(this).toggle();});`